# Connection refused error in command line Magento installation 2.4.1?

Tags: installation, magento2.4

Magento removed web installation in 2.4.1 version, while installing from command line, I am getting below error:

```
 bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://dev.magento.local/ --db-host=127.0.0.1:3307  --db-name=magento24 --db-user=root --db-password=Admin@123 --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com --elasticsearch-port=9200

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

In InstallCommand.php line 274:
                               
  Parameter validation failed
```

Update:

I managed to fix this . **Please note the single quote in password**

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://dev.magento.local/
--db-host='127.0.0.1'  --db-name=magento24 --db-user=root 
--db-password='Admin@123$$'
```

Answer (score 0):

`--db-host=127.0.0.1:3307`
`--db-password=Admin@123`

Are you sure these are the credentials of your database?

`--db-host=127.0.0.1:3306` are you sure this isn't the port number of your mysql server??

Comment: Hi @Arbab , I have tried that also, --db-host=127.0.0.1:3306 it gives me invalid credentials error. But my username and password is correct. Not sure what is happening.